# Add Child Element to Parent on a Set of Matched Elements, and use Parent Div href - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a situation where I need to append a child div to a set of elements. The child element is a div that has an anchor link that takes the href from its parent element.

When I did this initially only using one div it was all straightforward enough, but now I'm trying to get it to work on a set of elements with a CSS class selector I seem to be just going round in round in circles and it's getting very frustrating :(

Here is a codepen link: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/XgrqWZ

Here is a 2nd codepen to how it should look (this example has only one parent element): https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/RgbawK

Another problem that has just occurred to me is, how do i have it so that each child element always takes is href from the parent element when there are a number of instances using the same class?

Any help would be amazing. Emily.

HTML

```
<div class="outerbox">
  <a href="https://www.google.co.uk">Here is a job Title</a>
</div>

<div class="outerbox">
  <a href="https://www.bbc.co.uk">Here is a job Title</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {font-family: arial; color: white;}

body {display: flex; justify-content: space-around;}

.outerbox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.outerbox a {margin-right: auto; margin-bottom: auto;}

.innerbox {
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px 30px;
}

.innerbox a {  text-decoration: none;}
```

JS

```
// DECLARE OUTERBOX
var outerbox = document.querySelectorAll('.outerbox');

// GET PARENT ELEMENT HREF ATTRIBUTE
var parentLink = document.querySelectorAll('.outerbox a');

for (var i = 0; i < parentLink.length; i+=1) {
  var innerHREF = parentLink[i].getAttribute("href");
}

// CREATE INNERBOX
var innerBox = document.createElement('div');
innerBox.classList = "innerbox";

// CREATE ANCHOR LINK AND PASS IN HREF VAR
var anchorTag = document.createElement('a');
anchorTag.setAttribute("href", innerHREF); // pass in innerHREF var
anchorTag.appendChild(innerHREF);
anchorTag.innerHTML = "Apply";

for (var j = 0; j = innerbox.length; j+=1) {
  innerbox[j].appendChild(anchorTag) 
}

// ADD INNERBOX TO OUTERBOX

outerbox.appendChild(innerBox);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your javascript has some errors, try this

```
        <script>
          document.querySelectorAll('.outerbox').forEach(function(element){
            //get parent link
            //var innerHREF=element.querySelector('a').href;
            //you need no var, i put it direct on line marked with //*****
            //create innerBox
            var innerBox = document.createElement('div');
            innerBox.classList.add('innerbox');
            // CREATE ANCHOR LINK AND PASS IN HREF VAR
            var anchorTag = document.createElement('a');
            anchorTag.setAttribute("href", element.querySelector('a').href); //***
            anchorTag.innerHTML = "Apply";
            innerBox.appendChild(anchorTag);
            element.appendChild(innerBox);
        });
  </script>
```

Comment: [`nodeList.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).

Comment: that´s correct. IE don´t know `nodeList.forEach`, but also don´t know Array.forEach.

IE knows `[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.outerbox'),function(element){`

Comment: Hi will the amended answer now work in IE or will I need to make further amendments (I'm not bothered about IE < 9). Thanks, Emily.

Comment: No, for IE you must take `[].forEach.call (document.querySelectorAll('.outerbox'),funct‌​ion(element){`

Comment: So will the above method work on all browsers after IE 10 (IE11 and Edge)? Or will I have to change the first bit to make sure it works in all Microsoft browsers? I'm really confused.
The CSS was only for the demo, it's not on the actual site.  I realise it was a bit rushed.  Thanks for your help. Emily.

Comment: yes, i have tested this with IE. For future check [canIuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=forEach)